# Examples of non-hamiltonian decomposable graphs

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, topological-graph-theory

Good Afternoon!

I read that Line graph of the Petersen graph is 4-regular 4-edge-connected and non-hamiltonian decomposable. Does someone knows examples (or references) of non-hamiltonian decomposable graphs?

Thanks

Comment: Any [non-hamiltonian graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonhamiltonianGraph.html), for a start. Or any graph whose number of edges isn't an integer multiple of its number of vertices. Can you narrow down a bit more what you're looking for? PS Mathworld's page on [Hamilton decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonDecomposition.html) may have what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes, non-hamiltonian and uniquely hamiltonian are not hamiltonian decomposable. I am searching examples of not-uniquely-hamiltonian not-hamiltonian decomposable 4-regular graph. I have $G=C_2\times C_3$, but how can i prove (whitout a computer program) that $G$ is not-hamiltonian decomposable?

Comment: Either I'm misunderstanding your notation or $C_2 \times C_3 = K_6$, which is 5-regular. Note also the statement in the second MathWorld page I linked that every Hamiltonian vertex-transitive graph with no more than 31 vertices has a Hamilton decomposition except the line graphs of the Petersen and Coxeter graphs. The next smallest known non-decomposable vertex-transitive graph has 48 vertices, so if you're looking for examples which can be checked by hand you almost certainly want to look at non-vertex-transitive graphs.

Comment: With $G=C_2 \times C_3$ means [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs)  between digon $C_2$   and triangle $C_3$  , $G$ $4$-regular but not simple. Thanks for you reply.

Answer (score 1):

I had written code to find Hamiltonian decompositions (HD) and thought that, with only small counterexamples, all vertex transitive (VT) graphs would be HD. Not so, as was recently proved. It is well known that there are five (connected) VT graphs that are not Hamiltonian. I had conjectured that every Hamiltonian VT graph is HD except the line graph of the Petersen graph. I checked that the conjecture is true for all VT graphs with vertex count up to 30. Seemed like good evidence. Nope. The conjecture is false. Bryant and Dean recently showed how to construct counterexamples. See: http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5211

Comment: Thanks for the valuable reference. As soon as possible I'm going to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Two obvious necessary conditions for a graph to be Hamilton decomposable are:

- it is Hamiltonian (which implies it is connected), and
- it is regular with even vertex degrees (since Hamilton cycles are $2$-regular).

Any graph that does not satisfy all three of these conditions will not be Hamilton decomposable.

---

In response to the comment: $C_2 \times C_3$ (where $\times$ is the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs)) has $$|V(C_3)| \times |E(C_2)|+|V(C_2)| \times |E(C_3)|=9$$ edges.  It can't be Hamilton decomposable since the number of edges is not divisible by $|V(C_2 \times C_3)|=6$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Rebecca J. Stones, but $C_2 \times C_3$ is a multigraph without loops and has size twelve, the underlying simple graph (without parallel edges) has nine edges. Cheers!